# Error in R: I should use rep() but I already do

Tags: r, rep

I'm using a small code in R:

`dat$colour<-rep(rainbow(4)) #you get a warning if you not have a multiple of 4 records, but that is ok.`

`dat` consists of seven rows. I've included `rep()` to make sure that the colours can be repeated even though seven is not a multiple of four. However, I still get the following error:

`Error in set(x, j = name, value = value) :  Supplied 4 items to be assigned to 7 items of column 'colour'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.`

To reproduce:

```
dat <- data.table('Year' = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016))
dat$colour<-rep(rainbow(4))
```

I would really value the help, the script is automated but now gives me this error.
I have just switched to a new computer, the problem may lie in an incorrect version of this or that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rep_len`:

```
dat$colour <- rep_len(rainbow(4), nrow(dat))
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work! But why do I even get the error? I've used the script a long time and haven't seen it before

Comment: In case `nrow(dat) %% 4 == 0` your script will in case of `rainbow(4)` work without error as it replicates automatically.